# Command line syntax checker for Racket / Scheme

Tags: vim, scheme, racket, syntax-checking, syntastic

I'm looking for a command-line tool to check the syntax of my Racket / PLT-Scheme code. The purpose of this is to build a syntax-checker for [Syntastic Vim plugin](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic).

Has anybody heard of a way?

Comment: You should ask that on Racket's mailing lists. They are very quick to respond.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're looking for a code style checker, check out Eli Barzilay's ["code ayatollah"](http://tmp.barzilay.org/code-ayatollah.rkt).  You can run that on the command line.

Comment: This indeed looks like the best thing going on at the moment. I spoke to Eli and asked for permission to continue development and merge it to Syntastic, if anybody is willing to do that.